# Install go-swagger on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: go, ubuntu, go-swagger

I want to install go-swagger on LInux Ubuntu 22.04 but i have blocker. This is my code to install go-swagger.

```
sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https gnupg curl
curl -1sLf 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/go-swagger/go-swagger/gpg.2F8CB673971B5C9E.key' | sudo apt-key add -
curl -1sLf 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/go-swagger/go-swagger/config.deb.txt?distro=debian&codename=any-version' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/go-swagger-go-swagger.list
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install swagger
```

but the result on my laptop

```
Unable to locate package swagger
```

please help me to the solving my blocker

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the [bug on Caddy](https://github.com/caddyserver/dist/issues/83) due to changes in CloudSmith. Run

```
sudo apt install -y debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring apt-transport-https

curl -1sLf 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/go-swagger/go-swagger/gpg.2F8CB673971B5C9E.key' | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/go-swagger-go-swagger-archive-keyring.gpg
```

to import the key.